# Laravel duda sobre foreach anidado, agrupar resultado

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Necesito ayuda de algún experto, ya que no soy programador pero estoy trabajando en una página web con laravel. Estoy tratando de obtener los registros de mi tabla estatutos agrupados por categoría que obtengo del primer Query que me saca la categoría, ya intenté de muchas formas y no logro conseguir el resultado que busco por lo que regresé al punto donde iba bien. probablemente sea algo muy sencillo por favor no me regañen :(.
los resultados los muestro en un acordeón (vista).

**TABLE categorias**

| id | nombre_categoria |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | categoria1 |
| 2 | categoria2 |

**TABLE estatutos**

| id | categoria_id | titulo | descripcion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | titulo1 | descripción 1 |
| 2 | 1 | titulo1 | descripción 2 |

llave foránea categoria_id (estatutos) -> id (categorias).

**Modelo Estatutos** aquí es donde aplico la relación

```
class Estatutos extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table="estatutos";   
    public function Categorias(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categorias::class, 'categoria_id', 'id');
    }        
}
```

**Modelo Categorias**

```
class Categorias extends Model
{
    protected $table="categorias"; 
}
```

**controllador**

```
 public function index(){            
 
        $categorias = Estatutos::groupBy('categoria_id')
        ->get(); 
        //con esto saco los titulos y los agrupo para mostrarlos en mi vista
        
        $estatutos = Estatutos::all();  
        //muestro el resto de los datos de mi tabla estatutos (lo que quiero es obtener solo los registros que pertenezcan a la categoría)

        return view('socios.estatutos')
        ->with('categorias', $categorias)
        ->with('estatutos', $estatutos);
    }
```

**Vista**

```
    @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)  
    {{$categoria->categorias->nombre_categoria}}//muestro los titulos
       @foreach ($estatutos as $estatuto)                   
                {{$estatuto->titulo}}
                {{$estatuto->descripcion}}//en este segundo foreach es donde quiero mostrar unicamente los registros que pertenezcan a esa categoría
       @endforeach   
    @endforeach
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, si haces `dd($categorias);` en tu función `index` justo después de obtener tus categorías ¿Qué es lo que obtienes? No has puesto la estructura de tus tablas pero al devolver una colección agrupada ya deberían venir los estatutos y por lo tanto podrías iterar en ellos. El problema es que obtienes una nueva colección `$estatutos` donde obtienes todos los elementos pero sin agrupar y por eso te aparecen todos en cada elemento.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe haber otra solución más fácil usando With, pero esto fue lo que se me ocurrió.

Simplificamos a una sola consulta con un join

**Controlador**

```
public function index(){
    $estatutos = Estatutos::from('estatutos as e') //alias
                    ->join('categorias as cat', 'cat.id', '=', 'e.categoria_id')
                    ->get();  

    return view('index')
        ->with('estatutos', $estatutos);
}
```

**Vista**

Cada ciclo va a colocar el nombre del estatuto, lo que hay que hacer es que coloque el nombre de la categoría solo cuando vaya a cambiar. Para eso, guardas el valor de la categoría y la comparas con la siguiente, si es diferente significa que se tiene que poner.

```
@php
    $categoria = '';
@endphp
<table>
@foreach ($estatutos as $estatuto)  
    @if( $estatuto->categorias->nombre_categoria != $categoria )
        <tr>
            <th>{{$estatuto->categorias->nombre_categoria}}</th> 
        </tr>  
    @endif
    <tr>                
        <td>{{$estatuto->titulo}}</td>
        <td>{{$estatuto->descripcion}}</td>
    </tr>  
    @php
        $categoria = $estatuto->categorias->nombre_categoria;
    @endphp
@endforeach  
</table>
```

Lo hice como una tabla, sino lo nececesitas así le puedes quitar esa parte y listo

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema es que al iterar con `foreach` tienes dos colecciones que a pesar de obtener elementos del mismo modelo, no están relacionadas.

Estás obtieniendo tus categorías así:

```
$categorias = Estatutos::groupBy('categoria_id')->get();
```

Y luego obtienes todos los estatutos así:

```
$estatutos = Estatutos::all();
```

Pero `$categorias` ya tiene todos los estatutos de forma agrupada por lo que la colección `$estatutos` no es necesaria.

Lo que debes hacer es utilizar la información que ya existe de forma organizada en `$categorias`.

Cree un ejemplo genérico para que lo entiendas mejor:

```
// Colección que representa lo que tiene el modelo
$collection = collect([
    ["id" => 1, "name" => "Apple", "category" => "fruit"],
    ["id" => 2, "name" => "Banana", "category" => "fruit"],
    ["id" => 3, "name" => "Carrot", "category" => "vegetable"],
    ["id" => 4, "name" => "Broccoli", "category" => "vegetable"],
    ["id" => 5, "name" => "Grapes", "category" => "fruit"],
    ["id" => 6, "name" => "Orange", "category" => "fruit"],
    ["id" => 7, "name" => "Potato", "category" => "vegetable"],
    ["id" => 8, "name" => "Spinach", "category" => "vegetable"],
    ["id" => 9, "name" => "Tomato", "category" => "vegetable"],
    ["id" => 10, "name" => "Cucumber", "category" => "vegetable"],
]);

// Simulación de la consulta con groupBy
$groupedFoods = $collection->groupBy('category');

// foreach que itera en las categorías
// Nota como obtenemos llave y valor
// La llave es la categoría y el valor serían los elementos de cada categoría
foreach ($groupedFoods as $category => $foods) {
    echo "<h2>{$category}</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
    // foreach que intera en cada elemento "food" adentro de la categoría correspondiente
    foreach ($foods as $food) {
        echo "<li>{$food['name']}</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

```
<h2>fruit</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Grapes</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
<h2>vegetable</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Carrot</li>
    <li>Broccoli</li>
    <li>Potato</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Tomato</li>
    <li>Cucumber</li>
</ul>
```

Regresando a tu ejemplo debería ser:

```
@foreach ($categorias as $categoria => $estatutos)  
    {{$categoria->categorias->nombre_categoria}}//muestro los titulos
    @foreach ($estatutos as $estatuto)                   
        {{$estatuto->titulo}}
        {{$estatuto->descripcion}}//en este segundo foreach es donde quiero mostrar unicamente los registros que pertenezcan a esa categoría
    @endforeach   
@endforeach
```

Y en tu controlador:

```
 public function index(){            
     $categorias = Estatutos::groupBy('categoria_id')->get(); 
     //con esto saco los titulos y los agrupo para mostrarlos en mi vista

     return view('socios.estatutos')
        ->with('categorias', $categorias);
}
```